# Regex to match last character in string

Tags: regex

Suppose I have the following strings:
`cat I` `cat II` `cat III` `dog I` `dog III` `bird I`

I would like to match all strings with a `I`, but NOT `II` or `III`.

So the correct match would give me:

```
cat I
dog I
bird I
```

I had the thought of matching an `I` with no other character after it, but perhaps there is a more direct way.

What would be the regex for such a pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
^[a-z|A-Z|0-9]+[^I]\s?I{1}$
```

I think this is a more accurate solution.

[Try demo](http://regexr.com/3gjtt)

Answer (score 13):

Try this sentence:

```
^(.*[^I])\I$
```

`^` - begin of strings 
`(.*[^I])` - match any character other then `'I'` (`[^I]` means "Do not catch `'I'`") 
`\I` - match an literal `'I'` 
`$` - end of strings

Answer (score 8):

You can use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), so the regex can be like this:

```
^.*\bI\b.*$
```

#### [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nZfkB6/1)

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution:

```
^.*\bI\b$
```

This could be used like this in C#:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^.*\bI\b$");
var input = new string[]{"cat I","cat II","cat III","dog I","dog III","bird I"};
foreach(string text in input)
{
    if (regex.IsMatch(text))
        Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```